# What is the difference between get_all_reserved_instances and get_all_reserved_instances_offerings?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

Both belongs to boto.ec2 . From the documentation i found that get_all_reserved_instances returns all reserved instances, but i am not clear about get_all_reserved_instances_offerings . What is it mean by offering.
One other thing that i want to know is,what is recurring_charges ?
Please clarify ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_all_reserved_instance_offerings` method in boto returns a list of all reserved instance types that are available for purchase.  So, if you want to purchase reserved instances you would look through the list of offerings, find the instance type, etc. that you want and then you would be able to purchase that offering with the `purchase_reserved_instance_offering` method or via the AWS console.

So, perhaps a simple way to say it is `get_all_reserved_instance_offerings` tells you what you can buy and `get_all_reserved_instances` tells you what you have already bought.

Comment: what is the recurring_charges or recurring cost ?

Comment: Is offering instances are based on our already reserved instance or it is independent from our reserved instances  and provide by AWS ?

Comment: Some reserved instance offerings involve only a single, upfront cost while others require only a recurring monthly cost, while others involve both up-front and recurring monthly costs.  The offerings that are returned represent all available offerings and are independent of your current reservations.